# Testing a class with a bindable field in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

Let's say I have a class like this:

```
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';
export default class MyClass {
    @bindable text = null;
    bind() {
        this.message = `Message: ${this.text}`;
    }
}
```

And in my test code I have the following code:

```
import MyClass from '../../src/myclass';

describe('MyClass', () => {

    let sut;
    beforeEach(() => sut = new MyClass());

    describe('bind', () => {

        beforeEach(() => {
            sut.text = "my text";
            sut.bind();
        });

        it('should have a message', () => {
            expect(sut.message).toBe('Message: my text');
        });

    });

});
```

When I run this test I following error is thrown:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'getOrCreateObserversLookup' of undefined
            at getObserver (C:/Users/vinte/Documents/projects/mealcal/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating@0.15.1/aurelia-templating.js:2571:40)
            at MyClass.descriptor.set [as text] (C:/Users/vinte/Documents/projects/mealcal/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating@0.15.1/aurelia-templating.js:2628:9)
            at Object. (C:/Users/vinte/Documents/projects/mealcal/test/unit/myclass.spec.js:26:16)

I'd like to test that the bind method has the correct behavior based on the value binded to the bindable field.

How do you do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For unit testing your custom element with `@bindable` properties there is a helper method defined in the templating repo.

[Here](https://github.com/aurelia/templating/blob/master/test/behavior-testing.js#L43-L56) is an example of testing a custom element.

```
  it('should raise value change on simple custom element', done => {
    var ele = BehaviorInstance.createForUnitTest(SimpleElement);
    spyOn(ele, 'fooChanged');
    spyOn(ele, 'barChanged');

    ele.foo = 'new foo';
    ele.bar = 'new bar';

    setTimeout(() => {
      expect(ele.fooChanged).toHaveBeenCalledWith('new foo', 'foo');
      expect(ele.barChanged).toHaveBeenCalledWith('new bar', 'bar');
      done();
    });
  });
```

Basically, you need to create an instance of your element specifically for unit testing it.  Then you can spy on the methods or ensure that things in your bindable happen such as the `valueChanged` event.  Those unit tests should show the proper way to do both, so if you have any other questions please let me know.